# Getting a year and month from a number of a months in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'd like to write a function which:

- takes in parameter: a number of months (int)
- returns the year (int) and the month (int) of the timedelta between now and the number of input months.

Example : we are in may 2014, so:

- myfunc(0) should return (2014, 5)
- myfunc(12) should return (2013, 5)
- myfunc(5) should return (2013, 12)
- etc.

There is lots of documentation about datetime and calendar, so much that I'm a bit lost. Thanks for help.

**Note**: I need to get an accurate way to do it, not an approximation :)

Comment: `time.strftime('%Y, %m%'), time.localtime(time.time() - n*(60*60*24*30)))` ish.. averaged the number of days to 30 per month so that will be a bit off :) Use [monthrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthrange) to calculate the ammont of days by looping backwards in your function (instead of doing a one-liner)

Comment: Thanks for this but I need an accurate solution, not an approximation. I'll add it in my question.

Comment: We're more interested in what you've tried so far actually.. Cause you show 0 effort and you ask us to solve the problem for you.. Which we probably will because we just want to get this over with :P

Comment: If I knew how to do it, It would be already done, it has nothing to do with efforts. If I didn't show what I did, it's because I didn't know what to do... your comment is pointless.

Comment: Well I don't know everything there is to programming, but when i ask for help i still show the research that i've done and my conclusions.. This is a part of being a programmer, trying to figure out stuff on your own as far as possible.. Giving up because the docs are hard is a sign that either you havn't slept enough or you need more caffeine.. I've NEVER done this type of functions before but i managed to come up with a solution within 5 minutes by just reading the docs and testing my way through it.. See below, duno if it's 100% accurate but i think it is.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me life. As I tried to explain you, THIS time, I have no research/conclusion since I don't know how to do it at all..this has nothing to do with effort. If you check other posts, this is not the case. So please stop judging people.

Comment: When people stop giving downvotes for no given reason when helping out people with absolutely no code to fix, yea sure.. Until then we're doing all the programming for you (which is fine, as long as you learn a thing or two) but if we at the same time get heat for coming up with *anything at all* we're allowed to be a bit judgy in the process.. It's karma, give -1 without leaving feedback we'll spread jdugement.. Not saying you gave the minus tho :) And sorry for sounding meaner than i probably am. Just making sure you're not one of **those** kids..

Comment: I NEVER downvoted your answer...

Comment: I was thinking about posting an answer but it has become a dangerous thread now, any ways answer is achieve. One more point, I dnt want to sound professor 'by the book', but lets keep everything we do here as constructive as we can :) cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

def myfunc(num_of_months):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    num_of_months = today.year * 12 + today.month - 1 - num_of_months
    year = num_of_months / 12
    month = num_of_months % 12 + 1
    return year, month
```

Comment: You can get current_year by datetime.date.today().year and use the same for month (warning, this seems to be one-based).

Comment: That works very well, thanks. I actually had the feeling the modulo was a good solution to do it, but had no idea how to do this. I just replaced `datetime.date.today()`by `datetime.now()` but this changes nothing.

Comment: You have to use datetime.datetime.now() instead of datetime.now(). I recomend you to check my solution is accuracy and easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import strftime, localtime, time
from calendar import monthrange
def uberdate(n):
    if n == 0: return strftime('%Y, %m').split(', ')
    month = int(strftime('%m'))
    aDay = 60*60*24
    offset = aDay # One day to start off with
    for i in range(0, n):
        while int(strftime('%m', localtime(time()-offset))) == month:
            offset = offset+aDay
        month = int(strftime('%m', localtime(time()-offset)))
    return strftime('%Y, %m', localtime(time()-offset)).split(', ')

print(uberdate(5))
```

This produces:

```
[torxed@archie ~]$ python test.py 
[2013, 12]
```

Don't know why i got the downvote, but to quote OP:

> Example : we are in may 2014, so:
>
> myfunc(5) should return (2013, 12) etc.

And this is what my function produces...
Feedback people, give it before downvoting randomly.

Comment: What's the complexity of this solution?

Comment: You ment to say why*? If so this isn't really complex, it's just a manually programmable solution to the problem.. Since the OP didn't give any specifics I didn't think of looking much into existing libraries since he didn't bother to.

Comment: I'm talking about algorithmic complexity. If it does an operation for each month, not sure how it will work for a large input. Anyway it doesn't seem to work with years before 1900.

Comment: That's probably because unix `time()` stamps will become a negative value and the mathematical operation in my logic will fail.

Comment: Not sure. The magical date seems to be ['1901', '12'], whereas the time was negative "before" (after).

Comment: @user189 I could look into it, but the OP has already accepted the answer and the planet needs me elsewhere.. *ejects*

Comment: @torxed, this works (+1). However, it's a little more complex than the Alex solution.

Comment: @DavidW. Haha yea his solution was quite more elegant, I'd go with his solution as well. As I mentioned in the comments, I've never had to do this kind of task so I wasn't aware that there were libs that did this :) Thanks for the points, it feeds my hunger to help and learn ^^

Comment: @torxed Thanks for your help. I didn't downvoted, but I'm almost sure who did it..just watching who is so eager to get upvotes..

Answer (score -1):

**EDITED** (Changed the month addition to make the accuracy perfect)

**Now you can put negative number of months and get past dates**
I think this is what youre looking for

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import * 

def calculate_date(number_months):
    time_now = datetime.datetime.now()  # Get now time
    time_future = time_now + relativedelta(months=+number_months)   # Add months
    return time_future.year,time_future.month  #Return year,month
```

I've tested this script in my coputer and works perfectly

```
>>> calculate_data(5)
(2014, 10)
```

Comment: This assumes 31 days in each month, not counting leap years.. OP asked for a accurate solution (see comments above)

Comment: You are right, but through documentation I found this relativedelta that works perfectly for this situation, and the code is easy to understand in this way and the accuracy is perfect

Answer (score -1):

You can use `python-dateutil` module for this. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil

```
def return_year_date(delta_month):
    from datetime import date
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

    new_date = date.today() + relativedelta(months= -delta_month)

    return new_date.year, new_date.month
```